# Tableau - row range based on dimension

Tags: dynamic, filter, tableau-api, calculated-field

Say I have this data:

```
Current Last_Four Next_Two
15Q1    14Q1      15Q3
15Q2    14Q2      15Q4
15Q3    14Q3      16Q1
15Q4    14Q4      16Q2
16Q1    15Q1      16Q3
16Q2    15Q2      16Q4
16Q3    15Q3      18Q1
16Q4    15Q4      18Q2
18Q1    16Q1      18Q3
18Q2    16Q2      18Q4
18Q3    16Q3      19Q1
18Q4    16Q4      19Q2
```

I have a filter to choose the Current Quarter (first column),with this selected i need to bring all current quarters in the range of the Last_Four and Next_Two dimensions, so if for example i pick Current = 16Q1 the table in tableau should display the range from 15Q1 to 16Q3 in the columns, something like this:

```
Sales  15Q1   15Q2   15Q3   15Q4   16Q1   16Q2   16Q3
Prod X   ##     ##     ##     ##     ##     ##     ##
```

I tried to create a calculated field but no luck
I'd appreciate any help here

Answer (score 0):

You can make this a lot simpler for yourself. Just have a single date type column called **Period**, not a string, but a true date with month, day and year. It can hold any date in the quarter.

Add a date type parameter called **Date of Interest** and show the parameter control.

Add a calculated field called **Within Date Range** defined as

```
Period >= dateadd('quarter', datetrunc('quarter', [Date of Interest]), -4) and
Period <= dateadd('quarter', datetrunc('quarter', [Date of Interest]), 2)
```

Put **Within Date Range** on the filter shelf and select True

Finally put Period on the Columns shelf and expand to see quarters. If you put Sales on text, you'll be in business. Select the period you wish from the parameter control.

Bottom line, working with dates is more effective than working with strings that represent dates

Comment: Thanks Alex! this actually addresses the case nicely with regular dates.
I need to stick to the string manipulation since we have a custom fiscal calendar and a phantom period that adds some complexity to use regular dates (for biz reasons we skept 2017 at all, so we jumped from 16Q4 to 18Q1)

Comment: You could keep the same approach I showed, and just have a more complex definition of the calculated field [Within Date Range] to account for skipping over 2017.